# Android - Custom attributes on existing views

Tags: android, attributes, custom-attributes

Some libraries provide custom attributes you can use with existing views. For example in [android-binding](https://code.google.com/p/android-binding/) library:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://...."
  xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/" 
..>

    <TextView binding:text="FirstName" ...
```

Can someone explain how does it work?
How do you create said attributes? How do you check if they exist and apply needed changes to the view?